# Problem with sentences structures?

Tags: grammar

I have problem with sentences structures.

I have a sentence:

> When reviewing [Name of Bank] reports, the conclusion can be reached
>   that over the next few years demand for new solutions will be
>   maintained which will be adapted to working ...

It seems to me that this sentence have mistake. I was trying corrected sentence.

> 1. When reviewing [Name of Bank] reports, the conclusion can be reached
>      that over the next few years demand for new solutions will be
>      maintained, and ones  will be adapted to working ...
> 2. When reviewing [Name of Bank] reports, the conclusion can be reached
>      that over the next few years demand for new solutions will be
>      maintained. A new solutions will be adapted to working ...

I am not sure, which sentence is correct and better?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should write `the conclusion can be reached` it either has been reached or it has not. With that in mind I would write

> After reviewing Kowalski's Bank reports, I/we have reached the
>   conclusion that over the next few years the demand for new solutions
>   will be maintained. The new solutions will be adapted to working ...

if you want to continue the second sentence and it's quite short you could put the two together with a semi-colon.

> After reviewing Kowalski's Bank reports, I/we have reached the
>   conclusion that over the next few years the demand for new solutions
>   will be maintained; these new solutions will be adapted to working ...

If you are still in the process of reviewing the reports but have done so sufficiently to come to this particular conclusion you could change '`After reviewing ...`' to '`During the review of ...`' or '`While reviewing ...`'